# Can a java constructor have interfaces as arguments

Tags: java, interface, constructor

I was experimenting with Java Interfaces, and the following code gave an error.

In a class, a constructor takes Map as argument

```
public class ClassA{
  private Map<String,InterfaceA> testMap;
  ClassA(Map<String,InterfaceA> testMap){
    this.testMap=testMap;
  }
}



public class ClassB{
  ClassA testA = new ClassA(new HashMap<String,ImplmntsInterfaceA>); //1st declaration
  Map<String,ImplmntsInterfaceA> testMap=new HashMap<String,ImplmntsInterfaceA>(); //Second declaration
  ClassA testB = new ClassA(testMap);
}
```

`ImplmntsInterfaceA` is a class that implements `InterfaceA`.

Both the `ClassA` declarations are giving errors, first suggesting that Map constructor be changed to `HashMap` and second asking to replace `InterfaceA` generic to `ImplmntsInterfaceA`.

Can someone help with why is it not working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please provide us with a Stacktrace?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan: It's a compile-time error, so how would there be a stack trace?

Comment: Could you provide the actual code or at least something that does not contain obvious mistakes (missing parenthesis...). And finally, the exact error messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want to change `Map<String,InterfaceA>` to `Map<String, ? extends InterfaceA>` in the `ClassA` constructor signature (and field). Otherwise a `HashMap<String, ImplmntsInterfaceA>` really isn't a valid argument for it.

Consider what operations are valid on a `Map<String,InterfaceA>` - you could write:

```
map.put("foo", new SomeArbitraryImplementationOfA());
```

That's not valid for a `Map<String, ImplmntsInterfaceA>` as the value in the latter has to be a `ImplmntsInterfaceA`. The compiler is protecting you from that.

If you use `Map<String, ? extends InterfaceA>`, you won't be able to make any *write* operations within `ClassA` (because you won't know what values are valid) but you'll be able to *fetch* from the map, knowing that every value at least implements `InterfaceA`.

This is basically a more complicated version of why a `List<Banana>` isn't a `List<Fruit>`...

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your `ClassA` constructor.

```
ClassA(Map<String,InterfaceA> testMap){ // *
  this.testMap=testMap;
}
```

Now your construcotr(*) will accept `Map<String, InterfaceA>` type or `Map<String,InterfaceA>` implementation. Eg: `HashMap<String, InterfaceA>`.

You can change your constructor to following to accept  `HashMap<String,ImplmntsInterfaceA>`

Eg:

```
ClassA(Map<String,? extends InterfaceA> testMap){ 
  this.testMap=testMap;
}
```